# How to find that our data is stable or non-stable?

Tags: classification

I'm a beginner in data mining and trying to select best classifiers for a dataset. I have no vision about methods of selecting the best classifiers, but I read somewhere about stable and non-stable data and proper classifiers for them.

My main question is that "Is there any algorithm or even any scale to find out that how much a set of data is Stable/Non-Stable".

And secondly if everybody can help me how to find the best classifier it will be helpful.

Comment: Stability is not a property of the *data*, it's a property of a *model*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29), train your classifier on each fold, estimate the recognition rate, and then calculate the variance of the resulting recognition rates.

That should give you an idea of whether it is stable or not.

A grounded approach would be to estimate the confidence intervals of your measure of the recognition rate as the mean of the values resulting from cross validation. Nevertheless, there seems to be (to my knowledge) [clear](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/BengioG04.pdf) way to calculate those intervals. Apparently it is [no easy question](http://hunch.net/?p=29).

I use the first approach as a check. Just to make sure there is nothing fundamentally wrong.